# Real ICE with PIC18f26 on MPLAB 8.83 - Can't make it work

Tags: pic, mplab

I'm trying to use my real ice board under mplab 8.83.
I have already fixed some issues thanks to the microchip forum but sadly I have one last error that keeps coming up.
Few minutes ago it was :

```
Target Device ID not detected
```

and now that is not showing anymore but I get :

```
Target Device ID (00000000) does not match expected Device ID (00004c40).
```

I have switched the driver from MPLAB X to MPLAB 8, the self test of the real ice is working just fine. I also have tried to connect/disconnect the board. I have also tried with a ICD2 without success.

I am working with Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to solve my problem. 
It turns out, that having forgotten to install the MLA library, Windows was considering the REAL ICE as a common usb device (such as thumb drive). It was listed as "Custom USB Device --> WinUSB device" in the Device Manager.

After re-installation of everything (MPLAB, C18, MLA) , the REAL ICE is listed as "Custom USB Device --> Microchip Custom USB Device" and it works perfectly !!!

Comment: Since you stated before "I have switched the driver from MPLAB X to MPLAB 8, the self test of the real ice is working just fine." it really surprises me that you would have self test passed if WinUSB device driver was installed.

Comment: Indeed, it's quiet strange. And again thanks for you help. Really appreciated it

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing with Real ICE or ICD2 since it complains about device on your target board. You have to check connections between debuggers (ICD2, REAL ICE...) and hardware. If connection on ICD header is OK, next you have to check is power supply on hardware board.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to specify that the Real ICE (as the ICD2) and the target board are working on other computers. Mine seems to be the only one refusing to work...

Comment: Anyhow I have decided to use my colleague's computer. It works fine on his.